# How can I save a design in high resolution?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I have created a logo for a friend's business and they're wanting to get a sign made. The person they have contacted to make the sign is saying they need a bigger version of my design and in high resolution.  I don't know how to make it high resolution or make it bigger, other than just increasing the size in illustrator.

Comment: What's the nature of the art? Is it vector-based or just raster images in Illustrator?

Comment: I used paths in illustrator to create the logo. So I'm assuming that's vector-based? I'm new to this so I'm not 100% sure.

Answer (score 1):

Since you already did the logo in Illustrator, just send them the AI file or a PDF export. These are vector formats and they can scale these to any size so your logo fits the sign with no quality loss.

Answer (score 0):

When you start a new file in illustrator you can set it at print resolution, 300 dpi.

You can also adjust the resolution of your file. This shouldn't matter if your file is a proper vector. (No photo content, only illustrator paths)

Vector file types stay sharp at any size. Use illustrator to export or "save for web" a .PNG 24. Be sure to select transparent background.

You can also "save as" an .EPS, .PDF or .SVG, any of these should work fine for your printer.

The actual size of your artwork does not need to be more than a few inches. This can also be set at export.

If some of your design is not vector than export a .PDF or .PNG at 30 inches, or however the sign will need, plus some, so there will be no question of resolution.

If your art doesn't look good at this size than it needs to be recreated in vector or at final size.